# Every possible sum combination in a vector

Tags: matlab

Assuming I'm having a vectors of numbers A, for example: `A=[1 3 5 3 9 6]`(A's length >= 2) and an Integer `X=6`. Need to find how many pairs `(A[i],A[j])` where `i<j` exist in the vector which answer this condition: `A[i]+A[j]=X`. The number of pairs is printed.

Not allowed to use `for`/`while`. Allowed only `ceil`,`floor`,`mod`,`repmat`,`reshape`,`size`,`length`,`transpose`,`sort`,`isempty`,`all`,`any`,`find` ,`sum`,`max`,`min`.

Comment: It seems that this is a homework.

Comment: I need a general direction :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `repmat`, `length` and `sum` -

```
integer1 = 6; %// One of the paramters

A_ind = 1:length(A) %// Get the indices array

%// Expand A_ind into rows and A_ind' into columns, to form a meshgrid structure
A_ind_mat1 = repmat(A_ind,[length(A) 1])
A_ind_mat2 = repmat(A_ind',[1 length(A)])   %//'

%// Expand A into rows and A' into columns, to form a meshgrid structure
A_mat1 = repmat(A,[length(A) 1])
A_mat2 = repmat(A',[1 length(A)])   %//'

%// Form the binary matrix of -> (A[i],A[j]) where i<j
cond1 = A_ind_mat1 < A_ind_mat2

%// Use the binary matrix as a logical mask to select elements from the two
%// matrices and see which element pairs satisfy -> A[i]+A[j]=X and get a
%// count of those pairs with SUM
pairs_count = sum((A_mat1(cond1) + A_mat2(cond1))==integer1)
```

Outputs from code run to make it clearer -

```
A =
     1     3     5     3     9     6
A_ind =
     1     2     3     4     5     6
A_ind_mat1 =
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     1     2     3     4     5     6
A_ind_mat2 =
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5     5
     6     6     6     6     6     6
A_mat1 =
     1     3     5     3     9     6
     1     3     5     3     9     6
     1     3     5     3     9     6
     1     3     5     3     9     6
     1     3     5     3     9     6
     1     3     5     3     9     6
A_mat2 =
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     3     3     3     3     3     3
     5     5     5     5     5     5
     3     3     3     3     3     3
     9     9     9     9     9     9
     6     6     6     6     6     6
cond1 =
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     0
pairs_count =
     2
```

---

A bit more explanation -

Taking few more steps to clarify why `pairs_count` must be `2` here -

Set all values in `A_mat1` and `A_mat2` to be zeros that do not satisfy the `less than` criteria

```
>> A_mat1(~cond1)=0
A_mat1 =
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     3     0     0     0     0
     1     3     5     0     0     0
     1     3     5     3     0     0
     1     3     5     3     9     0
>> A_mat2(~cond1)=0
A_mat2 =
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     3     0     0     0     0     0
     5     5     0     0     0     0
     3     3     3     0     0     0
     9     9     9     9     0     0
     6     6     6     6     6     0
```

Now, add `A_mat1` and `A_mat2` and see how many `6`'s you got -

```
>> A_mat1 + A_mat2
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     4     0     0     0     0     0
     6     8     0     0     0     0
     4     6     8     0     0     0
    10    12    14    12     0     0
     7     9    11     9    15     0
```

As you can see there are two `6`'s and thus our result is verified.

Comment: Isn't this the wrong answer? 1 + 5 is 6, so is 3 + 3, so `pairs_count` should be 2. How does `mat1 < mat2` capture the index `i < j` condition? Isn't it making a mask where the *values* are less, not necessarily the indices? I think that's why it does capture the 1+5 case (since 1 < 5) but not the 3+3 case (since 3 == 3).

Comment: @Divakar it should be 2 pairs (according to the example). It's all about the indices, not the values.. prpl.mnky is right :/

Comment: I think you might want to make a `meshgrid` or something on the range 1 to `length(A)`, as your mat1, mat2 stuff, and then use the meshgrid for the condition, but then the arrays you have in your current answer for the check to see if summing equals 6.

Comment: Something is still a little fishy. You should be using the `mat1` and `mat2` that come from `A_ind` *just* for getting the index condition `cond1` (that looks correct now). But you should still need to make an analog of each of `mat1` and `mat2` from A itself, and use that in the last step for the sum ... otherwise you would be checking if index values themselves pair up to sum to 6. And for a value like 6, it's small enough that index values accidentally could, so your code might accidentally get the right answer.

Comment: In other words, you need 4 matrices: `mat1 = repmat(A_ind,[length(A) 1])`, `mat2 = repmat(A_ind',[length(A) 1])`, `mat3 = repmat(A,[length(A) 1])`, and `mat4 = repmat(A',[length(A) 1])`. Use `mat1` and `mat2` to create `cond1` then use `mat3` and `mat4` in the final line for `pairs_count`.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr Exactly , meshgrid does it in a more readable way! Thanks a bunch on the help!

Comment: @Divakar `A_ind_mat2 = A_ind_mat1'`   and    `A_mat2 = A_mat1'`  , right?

Comment: @DanielWatson The problem says - `"(A[i],A[j]) where i<j"`, but it wasn't mentioned whether `A[i]` is from a column vector version of A or the row vector version of A. More importantly, either way, you would end up calculating the valid pairs only and thus, the final result won't change. Try it, you would see!

Comment: @DanielWatson Just curious - Did the solution finally get you what you were looking for?

Comment: @Divakar indeed mate :)

Comment: @DanielWatson So, consider accepting the solution? :)